# Declare variable with format specifier in Go

Tags: go

In Python, I can declare a variable as `d ='/some/dir/%s'` and later replace `%s` with any value as

```
>>> d =  '/some/dir/%s'
>>> d % "hello"
'/some/dir/hello'
```

Is it possible to do the same in Go? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) does that:

```
d := "/some/dir/%s"
fmt.Sprintf(d, "hello") // Returns "/some/dir/hello"
```